# POST Image throwing "internal_error"

Tags: ibm-cloud, vpc

I'm trying to use VPC Classic POST Image REST API to upload the image to VPC. Getting internal_error

POST `https://us-south.iaas.cloud.ibm.com/v1/images?version=
2019-05-31&generation=1`

Body:

```
{
  "file": {
    "href": "cos://us-south/vnfimages/BIGIP-13.1.3-0.0.6.vhd"
  },
  "operating_system": {
    "name": "ubuntu-16-04-amd64"
  },
  "format": "vhd"
}
```

VHD Image is available in `COS`.

Expected Result:
REST API should pass and the image should be uploaded in vpc.

```
Actual Result:
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "internal_error",
            "message": "An internal error occurred.",
            "more_info": "https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/vpc-on-classic?topic=vpc-on-classic-rias-error-messages#internal_error",
            "target": {
                "name": "",
                "type": ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "trace": "f596852507fcd0c701eb46b63948ca63"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have created authorization between VPC Infrastructure (source service) > Image Service for VPC (resource type) and Cloud Object Storage (target service). 
Also the format field is not a valid field, you might want to drop it.